# Winforms chart: how to enable background color gauge

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, microsoft-chart-controls

I'm looking for a way to enable custom background color gauge in the Winform chart control library.  Here is an example:

[image]

See the green, yellow, and red color in the background?

Now, I need is a way to customize the background color gauge by controlling the starting/ending Y values, the color itself, as well as the number of different colors.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by adding [`StripLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.stripline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to the y-Axis of the `ChartArea`.

Their positions and sizes are controlled by their `StripWidth`, `Interval` and `IntervalOffset` properties.

All values are set in **data values**, so in the example above the three lines, bottom to top have `StripWidth` of 30, 40 and 30; their `IntervalOffsets` are 0, 30 and 70 and all have an `Interval` of 0, which means they don't repeat.

Let's try it:

```
Axis ay = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY;
ay.Minimum = 0;
ay.Maximum = 100;

StripLine sl0 = new StripLine();
sl0.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(64, Color.LightSeaGreen);
sl0.StripWidth = 30;
sl0.IntervalOffset = 0;

StripLine sl1 = new StripLine();
sl1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(64, Color.LightGoldenrodYellow);
sl1.StripWidth = 40;
sl1.IntervalOffset = 30;

StripLine sl2 = new StripLine();
sl2.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(64, Color.LightSalmon);
sl2.StripWidth = 30;
sl2.IntervalOffset = 70;

chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.StripLines.Add(sl0);
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.StripLines.Add(sl1);
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.StripLines.Add(sl2);
```

[image]